# How to force a view to be reevaluated when the same menu link is clicked twice in a row

Tags: dart, angular-dart

In the context of a single-page Angular.dart application, I have a menu choice implemented as the following link:

```
<a href="#/users/list">List users</a>
```

The routing is implemented as:

```
views.configure({
[...]
'users-list': ngRoute(
    path: '/users/list',
    view: 'view/usersList.html'),
[...]
```

});

The template *view/usersList.html* calls a controller which in turn calls a REST service on a server to obtain JSON data that it then formatted on the page.

When I click the menu link, the view is displayed and the controller is activated; everything works as expected. But when I click the same menu link a second time in a row, nothing happens.

I previously had this issue with Angular.js and I had fixed it by adding a trailing `/` to the route paths. This trick no longer works in Angular.dart.

Would anyone know how to solve this issue?

Comment: What do you expect to happen?  After the first click, the application is already in the usersList view, so clicking a second time should have no effect.

Comment: I would like the users to be able to refresh the view by clicking on the same link they previously clicked to enter the view. I could achieve this with Angular.js, I suppose that there is a way in angular.dart.